# Turn off LogEnabled Filter at run time - Logging Enterprise Application Block

Tags: logging, enterprise-library, application-blocks

so the story go like this:

i'm using the Logging Enterprise Application block that provided by microsoft to log events in our application.

The goal is to enabled event viewer logging at loading and then turn it off.

What i did is to add EventLog TraceListener which write all our logs into the event viewer. What i'm trying to do is to disable it after the application was done loading. The only way that i can thing about is to add a LogEnabled Filter and then turn it off.

However, i don't know how to access this filter at run time and disable log on this listener.

if you have an idea, please share.

Thanks

Comment: Is your TraceListener setup via configuration?  Do you want to programmatically disable logging?

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise Library logging offers a bunch of bits to twiddle.  So, before getting into changing the configuration maybe some of the out of the box settings can let you do what you want?

It sounds to me like you want your application to log some messages during startup and then not to log any more messages.  I'm assuming that you explicitly know when you are done logging startup messages.

If the above is true I think the easiest way would be to use the LogEntry Priority property.

In the configuration file setup a Priority Filter with a minimum priority of 2:

```
<logFilters>
  <add minimumPriority="2" maximumPriority="2147483647" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Filters.PriorityFilter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    name="Priority" />
  <add enabled="true" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Filters.LogEnabledFilter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    name="LogEnabled Filter" />
</logFilters>
```

Then during startup use a priority of 2 (or greater) to log your messages.  Then when you know you are done set the priority down to 1.

I would encapsulate it better but a code sample would look like:

```
public class MyApp
{
    public static int LogPriority = 2;
    public static readonly string MyAppCategory = "MyAppCategory";

    static void Main()
    {
        Logger.Write("Loading 1...", MyAppCategory, LogPriority);
        // ...       
        Logger.Write("Loading 2...", MyAppCategory, LogPriority);

        // Done loading so turn off logging
        LogPriority = 1;

        Logger.Write("Message not logged", MyAppCategory, LogPriority);
    }
}
```

Now if you ever want to turn on logging for the rest of your app, just lower the priority filter from 2 to 1 and everything will get logged.

Comment: Why that complicated? What is the LogEnabledFilter entry for if you cannot set it to false during runtime, means: disable logging?

Comment: Yes, you can disable logging by setting the LogEnabledFiter. The main way to do this would be to manually edit the configuration file -- this is the main intention of that functionality (developers guide references administrators tweaking this setting). Other similar approaches to setting the filter are to programmatically modify the original file-based configuration (which is essentially a reconfiguration of the block), or reconfigure the block programmatically (e.g. using the fluent interface). None of the programmatic approaches are what I would call simple

Comment: If you try to get the filter and disable it I don't think it has any affect without a reconfiguration.  So the following code still ends up logging: `var enabledFilter = logWriter.GetFilter<LogEnabledFilter>();  enabledFilter.Enabled = false;  logWriter.Write("TEST");`  One non-EntLib approach would just to manage the enable/disable yourself with a bool property and a helper class.  But I think the priority approach is a pretty straight forward alternative.

Comment: Just posted a question regarding this issue haha, ok I will do it via an external bool property :-). But can you explain why it doesn't work? 
The Logger.IsLoggingEnabled() always returns the initially loaded value.
Changing the value manually doesn't work as you described in your comment.

Comment: Why is `LogEnabledFilter` not updateable? The shocking answer you won't believe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39538868/disable-logging-on-fileconfigurationsourcechanged-logenabledfilter/39541912#39541912  :)