# How to rebuild Enterprise Library 6 on Win 8 and VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-8, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-6

I have customized the Enterprise Library and now want to rebuild it, but I get some errors when executing the BuildLibrary.bat (Scripts folder) from Developer Command Prompt for VS2015.

**Environment:**

1. Win 8
2. VS2015

**Two issues:**

**1.)**

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.
>   Build.Tasks.v12.0.dll

On my system I have a newer version:

> Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll

---

**2.)**

> "C:\EntLib6Source\Blocks\EnterpriseLibrary.sln" (Rebuild target) (1)
>   -> "C:\EntLib6Source\Blocks\SemanticLogging\Src\SemanticLogging.Database\SemanticLogging.Database.csproj"
>   (Rebuild target) (53) ->
>   "C:\EntLib6Source\Blocks\TransientFaultHandling\Source\TransientFaultHandling\TransientFaultHandling.csproj"
>   (Clean target) (35:11) ->   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(283,22):
>   error MSB4086: A numeric comparison was attempt ed on "10.0.11000.0"
>   that evaluates to "10.0.11000.0" instead of a number, in condition
>   "'$(TargetPlatformVersion)' >= '10.0.11000.0'".
>   [C:\EntLib6Source\Blocks
>   \TransientFaultHandling\Source\TransientFaultHandling\TransientFaultHandling.csproj]

---

> "C:\EntLib6Source\Blocks\EnterpriseLibrary.sln" (Rebuild target) (1)
>   -> "C:\EntLib6Source\Blocks\SemanticLogging\Src\SemanticLogging\SemanticLogging.csproj"
>   (Rebuild target) (52) -> (CheckPrerequisites target) ->
>   C:\EntLib6Source\Blocks.nuget\nuget.targets(71,9): error MSB4175: The
>   task factory "CodeTaskFactory" could not be loaded from the assembly
>   "C:\Windows\Micros
>   oft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0.dll". Could
>   not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.
>   Build.Tasks.v12.0.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.
>   [C:\EntLib6Source\Blocks\SemanticLogging\Src\SemanticLogging\Seman
>   ticLogging.csproj]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved it by overriding the toolsversion.
Didn't use the BuildLibrary.bat.

Executed msbuild directly with the following switches:

> msbuild.exe EnterpriseLibrary.sln /tv:14.0 /p:Configuration=Debug

If you want the Release version, replace debug with release.

P.S.: 
What I also did, was upgrading all projects to use .NET 4.6.1.
But I think, overriding the tv is enough.